# Active Threads Over Time displays incorrect graph

Tags: jmeter

I'm running a load test by 30 VU in non gui mode in JMeter 2.9.

Summarizer is showing that all VU got onboard as well Same in .jtl file,
but when I upload that file in Active Thread graph it's showing 0 VU.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view active threads in [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) you must set [save thread counts property](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/#Configure-JMeter) :

> By default, JMeter do not save threads count in JTL files. If you plan to work with JMeter JTL files, you should enable it by uncommenting in JMETER-INSTALL-DIR/bin/jmeter.properties the line:
>
> ```
>  #jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
> ```